# Complex row delete in sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have table (`TABLE_NAME`) like this :
[image]

I would like to check if count exceeds 5 and if yes, then delete row with lowest timestamp value. In this example, it should delete last row.

I would like to do it with one complex delete statement. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: is there a unique key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE TIMESTAMP < (
                   SELECT TIMESTAMP 
                   FROM (
                          SELECT TIMESTAMP 
                          FROM TABLE_NAME
                          ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
                        ) LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4);
```

With this query you:

- order the record by TIMESTAMP DESC
- select the 5th record TIMESTAMP (your minimum of the allowed values) --> min_timestamp
- you delete all the record with TIMESTAMP < min_timestamp

I didn't tested it but this should be the query to solve your problem.

Comment: In SQLite, `rowid`s come from the original table. Use `LIMIT` instead.

Comment: The outer `SELECT` will return the *first* record.

Comment: Modified with the LIMIT instruction. Thanks for the help to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
delete from TABLE_NAME where timestamp IN (select min(timestamp) from TABLE_NAME where (SELECT count() FROM TABLE_NAME)>5)
```

It will check if your tableRecord count is grater then 5 then delete min timestamp record.

Comment: yup, my original query is query   >>>>>    delete from todoList where pk IN (select min(pk) from todoList where (SELECT count() FROM todoList)>5)